# include_once/require_once, getting cannot redeclare error

Tags: php, include

I have the multiple versions of the same file on my web server. I'm require_once-ing one of them from another file, and I'm getting a "cannot redeclare [function name]" error. Why is this happening if I'm only including one version of the file!? And how can I prevent this error?

My directory structure:

```
/root/subdir/index-where-I-require-files.php
/root/subdir/second-subdir/included_fileV2.php
/root/another-subdir/included_fileV1.php
```

And I'm using:

```
require_once('second-subdir/included_fileV2.php')
```

within my index file.

Comment: Is that file including or requiring other files?

Comment: Possibilities are **A** your included file is including other files which have a function name conflict, or **B** your main script is defining a function that your included script is also defining.

Comment: @jszobody The file is a db file with my CRUD functions, it requires only its associated class file, which includes nothing else.

Comment: your "cannot redeclare [function name]" will tell you exactly _where_ it's being declared and redeclared, so that should narrow it down pretty quick for you.

Comment: Yes, it's telling me its being redeclared in the other directory. My question is why is this a problem, if the files have no connection via includes...

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea WHY it worked, but using an absolute path as opposed to a relative path seemed to fix things for me.